# Font-awesome icons on the same web page, some icons mismatch code, and some only show squares

Tags: css, frontend, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome in my Django project, as icons in front of nav-bar list. My problem is, as the title says, some icons show up normally, some icons show square with 4-digit unicode inside, and some icons show up but mismatch the code. What a mess!

I've been stuck here for long, and i tried a lot to solve it. Read the docs through, and googled a lot, but no effective solutions found.

---

**Environment information:**

1. I'm using the latest version of Font-awesome(4.6.3) **local copy** on linux server(Ubuntu 14.04).
2. I've tried to load this page on Chrome/Firefox/IE, the results are no different.
3. I've tried to disabled the AdBlock plugin, resulted in vain.

**Specific code:**

1. The 1st icon is normal.
2. The 2nd icon only show square with unicode (the same with [official](http://fontawesome.io/icon/key/)).
3. The 3rd one show a mismatch icon.

```html
<li class="openstack-panel">
    <a class="openstack-spin" tabindex="6">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
    Security Group
    </a>
</li>
<li class="openstack-panel">
    <a class="openstack-spin" tabindex="7">
    <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
    Key Pairs
    </a>
</li>
<li class="openstack-panel">
    <a class="openstack-spin" tabindex="8">
    <i class="fa fa-git fa-fw"></i>
    Floating IP
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is how icons are displayed on browser:

[image: here is how icons displayed on browser]

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me on Chrome on Windows - are you linking to font-awesome, or using a local copy?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the console log (dev tools chrome)?

Comment: @CalvT i'm using local copy.

Comment: @LaurIvanwhat info do you want? there is some errors, but seem to have nothing with icon.

Comment: @Leon I'd say your problem is the fact it's local then. You do have the `.eot` and `.woff` files the CSS files expects to find local as well?

Comment: @CalvT I do have `font-awesome.eot` and `font-awesome.woff` files under `font-awesome/fonts/` directory, but i don't know how to check if they can be found by CSS files...any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link for Font Awesome and try,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

or

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css
```

Comment: THX, still the same